# Handling commas within quotes when exporting a CSV file C#4.Any suggestions

Tags: c#, csv

Hi all
I am reading a csv file and I have encounted a problem when there is a comma inside the field

It all works till I get a comma within a comma
all the fields will have "" around it.

```
             string delimiter=",";
         using (var sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
        {
                sr.ReadLine(); //skip headers
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                   var readline = sr.ReadLine();
                   if (readline == null) continue;
                   var fields = readline.Split  (delimiter.ToCharArray());  
                 }
            }if I CANNOT split because of commas within quotation . How can I recode it?
```

I cannot use open source or thirdy party libraries.

Any suggestions?

Comment: FYI newlines are permitted between "" in CSV and "" for \". Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values and RFC4180.

Comment: `I cannot use open source or thirdy party libraries.` - what a pity, CSV isn't quite as simple as one first may think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) class.

The description on MSDN is:

> Provides methods and properties for parsing structured text files.

It lives in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` namespace, so not third party nor open source.

It is a managed class, so you can simply add a reference, import the namespace and use.

Example usage:

```
using(var fileReader = New TextFieldParser("C:\ParserText.txt"))
{
    fileReader.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
    fileReader.SetDelimiters(",");
    ...
}
```

Comment: It seems to be very close to RFC 4180 compatible. The only problem I found is that it trims leading and trailing spaces even if you double-quote.

Answer (score 0):

Since 3rd party libraries are out, a few choices (there are probably others):

- write a quote-aware CSV reader yourself
- use ODBC - see the last page [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/AccessTextDb12052005071306AM/AccessTextDb.aspx)

Comment: thanks for your replies.It looks like I have to reinvent the wheel