# How to handle quotation marks within CSV files?

Tags: c#, csv

To read a CSV file, I use the following statement:

```
var query = from line in rawLines
    let data = line.Split(';')
    select new
    {
    col01 = data[0],
    col02 = data[1],
    col03 = data[2]
    };
```

The CSV file I want to read is malformed in the way, that an entry can have the separator `;` itself as data when surrounded with qutation marks.

Example:

```
col01;col02;col03
data01;"data02;";data03
```

My read statement above does not work here, since it interprets the second row as four columns.

**Question:** Is there an easy way to handle this malformed CSV correctly? Perhaps with another LINQ query?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not a CSV as it's not comma separated. The likelyhood is you will need to write a small parser which checks for opening and closing quotation marks and ignores any specific characters eg. the separator in between them.

Comment: It is not malformed. There are several options, one would be to run through every character and remember the 'open' state of quotes.

Comment: This answer may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567691/handling-commas-within-quotes-when-exporting-a-csv-file-c4-any-suggestions?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#, regular expressions : how to parse comma-separated values, where some values might be quoted strings themselves containing commas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189416/c-regular-expressions-how-to-parse-comma-separated-values-where-some-values)

Comment: @WestDiscGolf it definitly is a CSV, normally the seperator used by the operating system is defined in the regional settings, which in my country and I guess for the Invariant culture too is a semicolon.

Comment: @Silvermind nice ... did not know that ... learnt something new today already. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 12):

Just use a CSV parser and [**STOP ROLLING YOUR OWN**](http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp):

```
using (var parser = new TextFieldParser("test.csv"))
{
    parser.CommentTokens = new string[] { "#" };
    parser.SetDelimiters(new string[] { ";" });
    parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

    // Skip over header line.
    parser.ReadLine();

    while (!parser.EndOfData)
    {
        string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", fields[0], fields[1], fields[2]);
    }
}
```

[`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is built in .NET. Just add reference to the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` assembly and you are good to go. A real CSV parser will happily handle this situation.

Comment: Well, I just learnt something new and its only 0830. Great success.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing CSV files manually can always lead to issues like this. I would advise that you use a third party tool like [CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) to handle the parsing.

Furthermore, it's not a good idea to explicitly parse commas, as your separator can be overridden in your computers environment options.

Let me know if I can help further,

Matt

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant but after using your method you can check if any colxx contains an unfinished quotation mark (single) you can join it with the next colxx.